# Python: update the last line and other lines asynchronously

Tags: python, printing, console, asynchronous

Say that I have a plenty of updating informations, and some variable that needs to display on the console constantly. I want to do the following effect:

```
Info 1
Info 2
Info 3
...
Info n
Var1: xxx, Var2: xxx <- The last line on the window of console
```

The info and variables may change differently, how to make those two parts change asynchronously in the console as well?

Answer (score 0):

For Unix, use [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html).

On Windows, one option is to use the [Console](http://effbot.org/zone/console-index.htm) module.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no need to change those parts asynchronously. You may use `\r` symbol to return the carriage on the last line and then use multiple spaces to clear it. The following python code should do the trick.

```
s = ''
for info in infos:
        print "\r", " " * len(s), "\r"
        print "info %s" % info
        s = "var1: %s, var2: %s" % (var1, var2)
        print s,
```

The question is that printing is going to be so fast that you will not be able to capture the output with your eyes, so may need add some sleep() function while printing.

Comment: Well is that means I have to record every info in the memory? Just make an example of an online chatting app, that those infos are messages, and variables are like online people num, messages num etc.